# Is a good practice to have an inner class for an embedded document when using a document based DB?

Tags: java, mongodb, couchbase, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-couchbase

During my initial approach of a Java application development with MongoDB, I find that my code doesn't look quite right with a flat Java class design and using inner classes seems to be a better approach. I am wondering how others design their Java classes in the regard and potential issues with inner classes for all embedded documents in DB. Here is a sample:

```
public class Account{
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    //...
    private Profile profile;
    //... 
    public static class Profile{              
         //...
         private Address address;
         private List<Comment> comments;             
         //...               
         public static class Address {
             // ...
         }
         public static class Comment {
             // ...
         }
    }
}
```

Is the above nested class design better to a flat class design as the followings?

```
public class Account{
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    //...
    private Profile profile;
    //...        
}
public class Profile{              
         //...
         private Address address;
         private List<Comment> comments;             
         //...          

}
public class Address {
             // ...
}
public class Comment {
             // ...
}
```

Comment: I find the question a bit vague. Could you post some examples?

Comment: I don't see how that makes a difference to the database. Whether or not the design is appropriate for your application, though, depends entirely on your application. The examples you posted don't *seem* to make much sense as inner classes (should something as general as `Address` really be composed into `Profile`?), but it's hard to say anything meaningful without more information.